# Breakpoints and Watch-list not working when debugging JS in Chrome

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome, debugging, google-chrome-devtools

We have two projects built on the AngularJS. When I debug JS in ViewModels of the first project, everything is fine. In the second one however, I can't put breakpoint on most of source lines, and when I manage to put them somewhere, they "fall through" on a next line or even further. Watch list and Local list also do not display variables correctly. The `debugger` keyword is also not working. How do i fix this, and why exactly it differs between the projects?

[image]

Comment: Sounds like source-mapping info is generated incorrectly or there's a bug in Chrome. Your bundler may also strip `debugger` from production code.